# Redirect URL on mobile

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

**How do you create a HTTP 302 in order to redirect mobile users to a different URL: *example.com* to *m.example.com* ?**

Google recommends HTTP 302 for redirecting mobile users:

"*HTTP redirection is commonly used to redirect clients to device-specific URLs. (...) It does not matter if the server redirects with an HTTP 301 or a 302 status code, but use of 302 is recommended whenever possible.*"

As a better technique than JavaScript redirect:

"*Be aware of the latency caused by the client side of redirection due to the need to first download the page, then parse and execute the JavaScript before triggering the redirect.*"

https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls

Comment: you need to do it on the server, which server are you talking about?

Comment: Sure @david.lucky Can you make the question more specific so I know what answer to provide?